# Ada Generic Formal Subprograms

Tags: generics, tree, procedure, ada

I'm doing an Ada assignment for school. My teacher has provided me with the following code. This is for a generic tree.

```
generic
    type Item_Type is private;
    with procedure put(i : Item_Type);
```

I create a new generic tree in my test file, as so.

```
package FrequencyTree is new Tree_Pkg (FrequencyRecord);
use FrequencyTree;
```

And now I get the following errors.

```
treetest.adb:12:01: missing actual "put"
treetest.adb:12:01: in instantiation of "Tree_Pkg" declared at tree_pkg.ads:4
treetest.adb:12:01: instantiation abandoned
```

I know that I am supposed to somewhere and somehow implement this procedure `put`, but where and how?

Answer (score 3):

The supplied generic unit declares *both* a [*formal type*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-5.html) and and a [*formal subprogram*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-6.html), so its generic [instantiation](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-3.html) requires *both* an actual type and an actual subprogram. Your actual type is `FrequencyRecord`; your actual subprogram should be a procedure that accepts a parameter of the actual type, `FrequencyRecord`. Then you can [instantiate](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-3.html) `Tree_Pkg` with the required actual parameters.

```
type FrequencyRecord is …;

procedure Put(I : FrequencyRecord) is
begin
   …
end;

package FrequencyTree is new Tree_Pkg (FrequencyRecord, Put);
```

Addendum: As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703373/230513) and [here](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-6.html), the profile of the actual subprogram must conform to that of the formal subprogram, but the name may differ.

Answer (score 2):

As to where and how, after studying [trashgod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43702354/4449975), consider that for the following to work:

```
package FrequencyTree is new Tree_Pkg
  (Item_Type => FrequencyRecord, 
   Put       => YourOwnPut);
```

it must be true that before you do this instantiation, both `FrequencyRecord` and `YourOwnPut` must exist: An Ada compiler here reads your Ada text from start to end, so when it sees the instantiation, it must have seen the two earlier.

This requirement means that you either define `YourOwnPut` on text lines before the instantiation of `Tree_Pkg`, to make both the type `FrequencyRecord` and procedure `YourOwnPut` exist before the instantiation line. Or, maybe chose some alternative arrangement: e.g., if  `FrequencyRecord` and  `YourOwnPut` can be placed together in a separate package, then you'd **with** that package in the context clauses of whatever compilation unit surrounds your instantiation line. (Judging by the error message, it might be called `Treetest`.) Say,

```
with Frequency_Stuff;

...
   package FrequencyTree is new Tree_Pkg
     (Item_Type => Frequency_Stuff.FrequencyRecord, 
      Put       => Frequency_Stuff.YourOwnPut);
```

So, when you do *this* instantiation, package `Frequency_Stuff` has already been seen and compiled by the compiler. IOW, if you make `Frequency_Stuff.FrequencyRecord` the actual parameter for `Item_Type`, and `Frequency_Stuff.YourOwnPut` the actual parameter for `Put`, then these actual parameters are existing already.